# Government Cloud and Encryption for data at-rest

Tags: shield-encryption, govcloud

If I walk out of a Salesforce Government Cloud data center with a disk or tape that contains customer data, I assume the disk or tape is encrypted. I won't be able to just mount the drive and browse it, right?

Government Cloud [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/solutions/industries/government/compliance/) has a section on Secure Data Centers...

> Data is protected in-transit and at-rest with FIPS 140-2 validated
>   encryption.

OK. Looks good, as long as this refers to data-center/storage-container level encryption (e.g. ssd/disk/tape) that is entirely managed by Salesforce and their IT team.

The above has nothing at all to do with customer-configurable Shield Platform Encryption, right?

Comment: Additional technical details about the implementation of platform encryption architecture including PCIe Hardware Security Modules: https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/reports/wp-platform-encryption-architecture.pdf

Comment: If you're looking for specific details about Government Cloud security and certifications, your Partner Account Manager / Account Executive can put you in touch with all of the resources to answer your questions.

Answer (score 3):

We went through a similar exercise with one of our clients. Whitepaper that @cropredy cites is enough of a hint - they want you to buy Shield, there's no "out of the box" encryption-at-rest at the data center.

Gov Cloud is a [set of products](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321821&type=1&mode=1) approved for use by US federal govt. It doesn't enjoy any additional data protection measures delivered by Salesforce at no cost to Gov Cloud clients. From Salesforce [Master Subscription Agreement](https://www.salesforce.com/company/legal/agreements/):

> **2.2 Protection of Customer Data.**
>
> SFDC will maintain appropriate administrative, physical, and technical
>   safeguards for protection of the security, confidentiality and
>   integrity of Customer Data, as described in the Documentation.  Those
>   safeguards will include,  but will not be limited to, measures
>   designed to prevent unauthorized access to or disclosure of Customer
>   Data (other than by Customer or Users). Except with respect to a free
>   trial, the terms of the data processing addendum at
>   https://www.salesforce.com/company/legal/agreements.jsp (“DPA”) are
>   hereby incorporated by reference and shall apply to the extent
>   Customer Data includes Personal Data, as defined in the DPA.

Data Processing Addendum:

> **6.1 Controls for the Protection of Customer Data.**
>
> SFDC shall maintain appropriate technical and organizational measures 
>   for protection of the security (including protection against
>   unauthorized or unlawful Processing and against accidental or unlawful
>   destruction, loss or alteration or damage, unauthorized disclosure of,
>   or access to, Customer Data), confidentiality  and integrity of
>   Customer Data, as set forth in the Security, Privacy and Architecture
>   Documentation. SFDC regularly monitors compliance with these measures.
>   SFDC will not materially decrease the overall security of the Services
>   during a  subscription term.

...and finally Security, Privacy and Architecture (SPA). Each "cluster" of SF products has one of these, here are the relevant portions from the SPA [doc](https://trust.salesforce.com/en/trust-and-compliance-documentation/government-cloud-plus/) for Gov Cloud:

> **Architecture and Data Segregation**
>
> Government Cloud Plus is operated in a multitenant architecture that
>   is designed to segregate and restrict Customer Data access based on
>   business needs. The architecture provides an effective **logical** data
>   separation for different customers via a customer-specific unique
>   identifier and allows the use of customer and user role based access
>   privileges. Additional data segregation is ensured by providing
>   separate environments for different functions, especially for testing
>   and production.

and

> **Data Encryption**
>
> Government Cloud Plus uses industry-accepted encryption products to
>   protect Customer Data and communications during transmissions between
>   a customer's network and Government Cloud Plus, including through
>   Transport Layer Encryption (TLS) leveraging at least 2048-bit RSA
>   server certificates and 128 bit symmetric encryption keys at a
>   minimum.

You'll want to read the entire SPA document, it's a good read.

No mention of data-at-rest encryption because (drumroll, please) they want you to pay for Shield and be responsible for key management. It's your data, after all. They're just holding it for you on a temporary basis, legally speaking.

Comment: appreciate the answer. I did read all of that prior to posting, good light reading. But, nothing in any of the Salesforce documentation I've seen directly addresses my question. Perhaps Salesforce doesn't care to disclose this level of detail to the world if sensitive data protection can be fully met with the paid feature.

Answer (score 2):

Shield Platform Encryption is a [feature available to Government Cloud subscribers](https://c1.sfdcstatic.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/industries/government/salesforce-security-white-paper-for-salesforce-government-cloud.pdf)

> *As outlined in the previous sections, the Salesforce Government Cloud has numerous configurable
>   security features that allow customers to customize security based on the sensitivity of the data
>   customers store in the application, consistent with the requirements in NIST SP 800-53 for moderate
>   impact systems. One such security feature is encryption. The Salesforce service provides the ability to
>   encrypt fields and files. Customers can implement Classic Encryption for selected custom fields, or, with
>   Platform Encryption (additional subscription option), customers can encrypt a variety of widely used 
>   14
>   standard fields, many custom fields and files and attachments. Encrypted fields utilize AES-128-bit keys
>   for Classic Encryption and AES-256-bit keys for Platform Encryption. Platform Encryption also allows
>   customers to manage the encryption key lifecycle. The encryption libraries for both Classic Encryption
>   and Platform Encryption are FIPS 140-2 validated [SC-13, SC-13(1)]. Additional security controls are
>   detailed in Salesforce’s Security Implementation Guide:*

As such, if a Government Cloud user wishes to protect SFDC data-at-rest by someone walking out of/hacking into the SFDC Data Center, they **should license Salesforce Shield Platform Encryption** and configure accordingly (decide which fields on which objects to be encrypted, decide on whether to encrypt platform events, search indices, files, chatter, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't follow your inference. We can't authoritatively infer that storage container level encryption is subject to software feature documentation... Flash Storage, Hard Drives, Tape Cartridges... the entire physical device and/or a storage partition on that device can be encrypted at a hardware level with minimal performance impact. It is becoming a de-facto standard in data centers. This wouldn't be something that Salesforce would allow customers to configure. They would control it (and the keys), as they would any other IT function such as backup.

Comment: I'd put my common-sense wager down that the Salesforce Government Cloud (and their Data Center vendor) is definitely employing encryption (FIPS 140-2) at a hardware level. But it isn't clearly documented down to that level of detail, other than the high-level quote I provided. Maybe it isn't important, because sensitive data compliance rules can be met with feature configuration (Shield Platform Encryption). Even so, I would like to see more documentation and information about how Salesforce secures their Government Cloud Data Centers. This was the point of my question...

Comment: Interesting.  Why offer Shield if the whole storage layer is hardware encrypted?